# Removing the multiple span tags present in the html content using c#

Tags: c#, html, .net

Please provide me the option to remove the multiple span tags present in the HTML content in c#

Eg - `<span style="abc">Welcome</span><span style="xyz">to C#</span>`

output - `Welcome to C#`

Answer (score 1):

When working with Html in C#, HtmlAgilityPack is generally the way to go:

```
private static void Main()
{
     HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
     html.LoadHtml(@"<span style=""abc"">Welcome</span><span style=""xyz"">to C#</span>");

     Console.WriteLine(html.DocumentNode.InnerText);
     Console.Read();
}
```

You can grab HtmlAgilityPack from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can remove the span tags using this:

```
Regex.Replace(content, "<[/]?span[^>]*?>", string.Empty);
```

But this will yield something like Welcometo C#, if you need to preserve spaces then you need to capture the groups and replace them with an space:

```
var content = @"<span style=""abc"">Welcome</span><span style=""xyz"">to C#</span>";

Regex regE = new Regex("<span[^>]*?>(.*?)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

var matches = regE.Matches(content);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    if (m.Success)
        content = content.Replace(m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[1].Value + " ");
}

content = content.Trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use a regex : `Regex.Replace(content, "<.*?>", string.Empty);`